# Type-checking a pattern match that panics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand what Rust's rules are around `!` and type-checking.

This function does type-check:

```rust
fn works<E>(r: Result<i32, E>) -> i32 {
    match r {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => {
            panic!("bad");
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas this one does not:

```rust
fn fails<E>(r: Result<i32, E>) -> i32 {
    match r {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => {
            panic!("bad");
            ()
        }
    }
}
```

This seems independent of whether I opt into the unstable `!` feature actually. With `fails`, I get a warning about unreachable code and an error ([E0308](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0308.html)) about the `Err` arm returning a `()` instead of a `i32`.

Why the distinction? I was under the impression that there's really no difference between `{ E; }` and `{ E; () }` - the former has no final operand, so is implicitly `()`, whereas the latter has a final operand, so is... explicitly `()`. But in this case, something about the presence of `panic!` causes the `;` there to not have effect.

Does `{ panic!("bad"); }` actually somehow have type `!` or is there some other way the compiler is simply suppressing the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is documented somewhere, and I don't know if it is intentional - you can try reporting a bug.

This difference stems from the fact that when there is a tail expression in the block, the compiler firstly expects it to matches the expected return type and emits an error if it does not. Only then it checks if the block diverges (has an expression that returns `!`) and allow any type if it does, but the error was already emitted.

[Here the compiler checks the type of the tail expression](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/6f8c0557e0b73c73a8a7163a15f4a5a3feca7d5c/compiler/rustc_hir_typeck/src/fn_ctxt/checks.rs#L1535-L1558), and [here it allows any type if the block diverges](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/6f8c0557e0b73c73a8a7163a15f4a5a3feca7d5c/compiler/rustc_hir_typeck/src/fn_ctxt/checks.rs#L1569).

[This is somewhat documented in rustc's source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/6f8c0557e0b73c73a8a7163a15f4a5a3feca7d5c/compiler/rustc_hir_typeck/src/fn_ctxt/checks.rs#L1559-L1565):

> ```rust
> // Subtle: if there is no explicit tail expression,
> // that is typically equivalent to a tail expression
> // of `()` -- except if the block diverges. In that
> // case, there is no value supplied from the tail
> // expression (assuming there are no other breaks,
> // this implies that the type of the block will be
> // `!`).
> ```